# Buscar archivos en diferentes discos de la PC

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes,

Tengo una aplicacion que escanea archivos y automaticamente los sube por FTP, pero me encontre el inconveniente de que si el dueño de el equipo configuraba que las imagenes cambiaran de ubicación al disco E:\ por ejemplo no me dejaba transitar por los dos discos, de hecho solo pude mirar el disco C, use %userprofile% y también Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables, las cuales hasta el momento no han tenido el efecto esperado, quedo atento.. muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Andrés. Por ahora, la pregunta no es clara. Tal vez necesites compartir el código que usas para aclarar tu problema.

Comment: como implementas la busqueda en el disco ? esta claro que la busqueda deberas realziarlas en todas las unidades de la pc

Answer (score 3):

Para poder realizar una búsqueda seguramente primero debas descrubir las unidades que se disponen, para esto usarías:

[DriveInfo.GetDrives()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx)

Entonces iterando cada unidad podrás realizar una búsqueda de archivos por medio de:

[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

Indicando la unidad y patrón de búsqueda, además si defines el `SearchOption` como `AllDirectories` realizará un barrido completo de toda la unidad, por supuesto si hay muchos archivos va a demorar.